# How to create a one-time ManagedScheduledExecutorService trigger

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to create a single-shot (one-time) trigger for a delayed task leveraging the [`ManagedScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html) in JEE7.  Following the sample in the javadoc, I've created a Trigger with a fixed timestamp that I was hoping would trigger a single time and automatically be removed from the scheduler once triggered, but that does not seem to be the case.  The trigger continues to be  called every millisecond, even after the trigger has fired.

```
   /**
     * Trigger class to create a fixed delay trigger by a set number of seconds from the time it is created
     */
    private static class FixedDelayTrigger implements Trigger {

        private Date fireTime;

        /**
         * Create the trigger with a delay from te time it is created
         * @param delayInSeconds
         */
        public FixedDelayTrigger( int delayInSeconds ) {
            fireTime = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(delayInSeconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        }

        @Override
        public Date getNextRunTime(LastExecution lastExecutionInfo, Date taskScheduledTime) {
            logger.info("Next scheduled time:{}", taskScheduledTime.toString());
            if( taskScheduledTime.before(fireTime)){
                return fireTime;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean skipRun(LastExecution lastExecutionInfo, Date scheduledRunTime) {
            // skip if the scheduledRunTime is after the scheduled firetime
            return scheduledRunTime.after(fireTime);
        }
    }
```

Consumer:

```
@Override
public void success() {

    // schedule the event to be sent after EVENT_DELAY seconds (enough time for the brute force detection to run)
    try {
        executorService = InitialContext.doLookup("java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default");
        executorService.schedule(() -> { super.success();}, new FixedDelayTrigger(delay));
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

In my logs, I see the following, so clearly the scheduler continues to call my trigger even after the scheduled time.

```
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
16:58:22,584 INFO  [managers.events.EventBuilder] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Next scheduled time:Mon Jul 16 16:57:54 EDT 2018
```

So how do i leverage `getNextRunTime` and/or `skipRun` if the `taskScheduledTime` remains constant, even after the job has run?  Is there a way to configure this to check less frequently?  Shouldn't a return value for `getNextRunTime()` in the past inform the scheduler that the job should no longer run and remove it from the scheduler?